# How to change texture.png after 3d.obj was placed in the surface using ARCORE?

Tags: android, colors, textures, augmented-reality, arcore

I've four types of texture.png for one 3d.obj file. How to change texture.png after 3d.obj was placed in the surface, like color changing functionality for ARCORE?

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the texture of the object.  Assuming you are looking at the hello_ar_java sample, you can add a method to `ObjectRenderer`:

```
  public void setTextureOnGLThread(Bitmap textureBitmap) {
    // Bind the texture name already allocated.
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    // Set the filtering for handling different sizes to render.
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

    // Copy the bitmap contents into the texture buffer.    
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, textureBitmap, 0);

    // Generate the mip map for the different sizes.
    GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // Unbind the texture.
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
  }
```

You need to call this from the GL thread, for example from `onDrawFrame()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am calling your code in ObjectRenderer getting null value after converting png into bitmap.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "converting png into bitmap"?  There is nothing special you need to do.  To load a png into a Bitmap, call  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mypng); Assuming mypng.png is in res/drawable.

Comment: getting same null value.. can you kindly provide the full code for texture changing in sample arcore sdk @Clayton Wilkinson